# Excel VBA - Dynamic Range obj referencing

Tags: vba, excel

Im doing what seems like a simple dynamic range. However, Im getting the following error:

"Error: Set method of range class failed"
VBA doesnt like the dropdownRange obj & throws the above error on the second last line of code below. I am using this range to be used in validation dropdown list further down the list.

```
Dim mainTab As Object   'Tab 'main'
Dim tranTypeSize As Integer 'Length of entries for transaction type
Dim dropdownRange As Range 'Dynamic range for dropdown
Set mainTab = Sheets("Main")

With Sheets("Misc")
    tranTypeSize = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    Set dropdownRange = .Range("A1:A" & tranTypeSize)
    dropdownRange.Select
End With
```

Comment: what value is tranTypeSize returning

Comment: @Sorceri tranTypeSize in an integer & outputs = 4

Comment: I just tested this (excel 2010) and it works fine,  addded data into a sheet named Misc in column A.  The only thing I can see that would cause the issue is tranTypeSize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you mean *Select* method of range class failed. If so, the problem is that `Sheet("Misc")` isn't active.

To fix it, put `.Select` as the first line of the `With` block.

Comment: You are probably right, come to think about it. Thanks